# shell script- sed pattern to enclose double quotes around array values ignoring space delimiter in a component

Tags: bash, shell

I want to enclose all the array values with double quotes ignoring the space delimiter in a component.

for e.g. i'm running the below bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

git checkout deltafinal

metaItems="$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only)"  #components involved in very last commit in git

# OUTPUT: metaItems=src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile

array=($(echo $metaItems | sed 's! src/!,src/!g'))

# OUTPUT: array= metaItems=src/profiles/API Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile
```

Now I want to put the double quotes around every array value starting from "src/" keyword, ending till ".profile" and store them in an array.

Expected Result:

```
"src/profiles/API Only.profile","src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile"
```

P.S. It should ignore all the whitespaces between /API and Only & /Chatter External User as shown above.

Please help.

Comment: It looks to me like you're constructing your array wrong, because it'll split elements based on whitespace, not commas. It's going to have the first element: "`src/profiles/API`" (note that I'm putting quotes *around* the element, they're not actually part of it), second element: "`Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter`", third element: "`External`", and fifth element: "`User.profile`". I'm guessing you actually want the first element: "`src/profiles/API Only.profile'", second: "`src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile`". Is that right?

Comment: Also, in shell syntax, you normally put quotes *around* data; putting them *in* data almost never does what you want. But it depends on what you want to do with this array. How are you going to use this array?

Comment: Did you create a new account or is this someone working on the same project as you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845037/shell-script-sed-pattern-to-ignore-whitespaces-in-array-values-only-ignore-not

Comment: Either way I showed how to properly construct a bash array from git diff output in an answer to one of the earlier questions from that account but there's this strange obsession with double quotes and commas, neither of which matter for bash arrays... I smell [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @GordonDavisson ..
I'm guessing you actually want the first element: "src/profiles/API Only.profile'", second: "src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile`". Is that right? 

Yes.. that's correct .. but currently it's splitting elements based on whitespace..

I'm iterating a for loop over this array ..which is splitting the elements as you mentioned above.

in case of 
for item in "${array}"

it should take 

first element: "src/profiles/API Only.profile'", second: "src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile`"

please help.

Comment: i'm working on the same project with Pravindra.

he might have asked this question earlier.

it's not XY Problem.

and the previous git diff output was not working as expected.

Word splitting was happening with that.

I want to iterate over this array later.. so word splitting should not happen.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will assign each filename to an array element as long as none of your filenames have embedded newlines.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

git checkout deltafinal

IFS_SAVE=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
array=( $(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only) )
IFS=$IFS_SAVE

# example: print array
declare -p array

# example: iterate over array
for path in "${array[@]}" ; do
    printf "path=%s\n" "$path"
done
```

Comment: thank you.. can you please post the entire script here..

how to use the array in for loop later ?

moreover.. it should not split the word(due to whitespaces between the element) during the iteration.

will it happen with it ?

Comment: I added some examples to my answer.

Comment: ... and the spaces will be preserved.

Comment: @MeenakshiBhandari You're welcome. If you find any answer that solves your problem, please feel free to vote up (▲) and/or accept it (✔︎).